# assign php variable to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How can i assign value of a javascript variable using php variable

```
 $(function(){
    $("select[name=myselectlist]").change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        if(id != 0) {       
            $.post("ajax.php", {"id":id}, function(){
                var data = "somedatahere";
                document.getElementById("namesurname").value = data;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

the code above works perfectly without php.Yet, i need to assign "var data" from mysql everytime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines) and a gazillion others.

Comment: [I wonder why they spent hours/days making the manual?](http://php.net/json-encode)

Comment: For that purpose you can use $.ajax in jquery

Answer (score 6):

If your php var is in the scope of the file where you have this function, you can do it like this:

```
var data = "<php echo $myvar; ?>";
```

Comment: Note: even if php var doesnt belong here  you can assign the SESSION variable similarly

Comment: idk why but it doesnt work for me, i mean when i use like; document.getElementById("namesurname").value = <?php echo $data['name']; ?>; value of text field with namesurname id doesnt change.

Comment: Try with the php var in quotes. If not worked cross check that $data['name'] is valid

Answer (score 2):

1) You can do as Shadowfax wrote but more simple:

```
var data = '<?=$dbResult?>';
```

2) More correct. Pass your result to AJAX response with `json_encode` function in PHP so you can rewrite your JavaScript code block as follows:

```
...
$.post("ajax.php", {"id":id}, function(response){
    $("#namesurname").val(response.data);
});
```

For example your PHP code block in backend may look like this:

```
....
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest')) {
    echo json_encode(array('data' => $dbResult));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this javascript code is in the php file, then you can simply use php variables as updated  in the code:-

```
<?php
// assign a value
$data = 'your data here';
?>

$(function(){
    $("select[name=myselectlist]").change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        if(id != 0) {       
            $.post("ajax.php", {"id":id}, function(){
                var data = "somedatahere";
                document.getElementById("namesurname").value = "<?php echo $data;?>";
            });
        }
    });
});
```